# What happened to Chromium tabs?

Tags: chromium

I had to close Chromium and when I launched it again my tabs look ugly:

[image: ugly tabs]

When they used to look like this:

[image: nice tabs]

They are taller and have lost the rounded corners.

Is this a "feature" of a Chromium update? Some other software update? Can I revert it?

I'm running: Version 51.0.2704.79 Ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit)

Comment: I get the same when I right click on a tab and then on 'Pin tab'. So you can probably revert it by right clicking on each tab and select 'Unpin'.

Comment: @grooveplex, no the first two tabs are pinned on purpose, that's not what I'm talking about. I guess I could have used a larger image for clarity.

Comment: Yes, please add a larger image because as it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @grooveplex, found an old screenshot so I added a before picture instead.

Comment: What is your chromium version?  (Can get by visiting the page chrome://version/)

Comment: So, you're talking about the rounding of the tab corners?

Comment: Added version, and yes, rounded, taller tabs.

Comment: Okay, yep.  It's just from the update from 50 to 51.

Comment: This is the design overhaul to the Material style. Other affected places are the back/forward/reload/stop buttons, the bookmark star, the https markers on URLs, the search box, and the menu button.

Comment: @otus I've edited my answer with a way you can manage to disable Material Design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tabs have been changed from Chrome and Chromium v. 50 to v. 51.  In version 51, Google has implemented Material Design by default, which has a more Safari'ish look.  It is up for debate which one is better looking.

http://cdn1.tnwcdn.com/wp-content/blogs.dir/1/files/2016/03/design.jpg

http://thenextweb.com/google/2016/03/15/material-design-coming-chrome-51-heres-looks-like/

To disable it, go to `chrome://flags` in chrome and chromium and search for `material design`.  You should come up with an option that says something like "Material Design in the browser's top."  Select from the drop-down "Non-material" and restart the browser.

Unfortunately, in version 51 of Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu, there appears to be bug that does not allow you to disable it straight from the browser.  It appears that it will, however, be fixed in v. 53.

You can disable Material Design in Chromium version 51 by running it from the terminal with the material design flag:

```
chromium-browser --top-chrome-md=non-material
```

...and if you want it to do that by default, simply search for the line in `/usr/share/applications/chromium-browser.desktop` that begins with `Exec=[...]` and add the `--top-chrome-md=non-material` right after `chromium-browser`.

Comment: Any idea if it's disableable?

Comment: Yes.  Go to chrome://flags (or chromium://flags - sorry, not sure which it is) and search for "Material".  Then select from the drop down "Non-material".

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately that does not do anything.

Comment: Even after shutting down the browser and restarting it?

Comment: Yeah, it automatically relaunches (and I tried manually), but the new GUI remains.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd.

Comment: Oh, well. The rest of the changes are fine, but I hate it when browsers steal my screen estate.

Comment: I'm still looking around: I'll let you know if I find anything.

Comment: Ok, @otus,  I'm going to summarise the information I've gleaned in an edit.

Comment: Is the bug that you found documented somewhere? My eyes are telling me this is worth doing an apt-get source to fix.

Comment: @Paul, I'm afraid I haven't found a lot of documentation.  I just know that I've got the same problem on my computers running Ubuntu, and that it's fixed in the unstable release.

Comment: @Paul, https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=591715